# Const declaration with react connected to mongo

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, constants, fetch, apexcharts

Good evening,
I have this component connected to MongoDb with a store :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {fetchCountries} from "../../actions/countries.actions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import formatCurrency from '../utils'

class Actual2020Sum extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            totalA: null,
            country: null,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchCountries()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              {!this.props.countries ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
                    ) : (
                    <ul className="countries">
                    {formatCurrency(this.props.countries.reduce((a,c) => 
                        (c.phase === "actual" && c.year === 2020 ? a + c.amount : a),0)
                    )   }
                </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state)=>({countries: state.countries.filteredItems}), 
    {
        fetchCountries,
    })(Actual2020Sum)
```

This is very helpful so far but I would like to simplify my code by being able to declare a const that allows me to put the result in the return part.
For instance :

```
render() {
  const Budget = this.props.countries.reduce((a,c) => 
   (c.phase === "actual" && c.year === 2020 ? a + c.amount : a),0)
}
return (
 <div>
{Budget}
 <div>
```

I believe that the const declaration is wrong but I just wanted to show that part is fetching data from Mongo.

The fact is that I am trying to implement data with apexchart and I don't know how to fetch data from mongoDB in the constants Actual & Budget.

So far I have this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts';


export default class ChartActualAchi extends Component {

    render() {

const Actual = 
const Budget = 
const ActBud = (Actual / Budget) * 100

const series = [ActBud];

 const options = {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'radialBar',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      radialBar: {
        hollow: {
          size: '70%',
        }
      },
    },
    labels: ['Actual vs Budget'],
  };
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactApexChart
                options={options}
                series={series} 
                type="radialBar" height={250} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope my question was clear enough and thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code with inline render is already about as simple as it can get, but if you mean you want to reduce the JSX then you can factor that logic out. Is there an issue you have with this code?

Comment: Hi, yes. I am trying to work with Apexcharts and I tried to fetch data from Mongo into the const options but without sucess. I edited my questions with more details.

Comment: Sorry, your question/issue seems less clear (*to me at least*) now. What and where are you fetching from your DB? It is difficult to see how the last snippet relates to the first two.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I am trying to do is to connect MongoDB to the chart. I imagined that if I can define a constant I could export the result in the const named "series" you can see in the second part (const series = [ActBud]. Hope this helps you.

Comment: So is `const series = [ActBud];` not working to pass data to the chart? Are `Actual` and `Budget` the values you get from the DB? Is the issue connecting to and getting these values?

Comment: The issue is to get the value from the DB into the const Actual & Budget.

Comment: Ok, can you again update your question to demonstrate how you are connecting to and querying your DB for these values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231083/discussion-between-add-and-drew-reese).